# How to force a call to getPlaceholderTemplate on Apple Watch simulator to update complications preview

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch-complication, watchos-3

I made the mistake of installing the app on the simulator without having set up all my complication templates.  As the docs state, getPlaceholderTemplate gets called one time and then cached.

So now that I have all my Watch complication templates set up, I want to text them out by customizing the Modular face. But only the one template I had originally created will show up, the rest have the white box. This is just the static template I'm concerned about.

I've tried deleting the app from the simulator, removing it via the Watch app, re-installing, but still doesn't seem to call the function again to update the templates.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I do to resolve this is click Simulator > Reset Content and Settings... in the Menu Bar for both iPhone and Apple Watch simulators.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the app and then re-install using the `Watch` app on iPhone Simulator